# Can I do a floating dialog from btn?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

So i need to do a floating window from v-btn like v-menu but dialog apears on the center of the screen
here is my code
if it possible can you help me to solve this problem
I'm not sure if it can be possible to do dialog floatable maybe it must be another component
I think i need to do it with another component cause dialog does not fit this
[image]

i need to do this
[image]

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card id="create">
      <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
        <v-layout child-flex wrap>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
            <v-subheader>Options</v-subheader>
            <v-checkbox v-model="hover" label="Open on hover" hide-details></v-checkbox>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
            <v-subheader>FAB location</v-subheader>
            <v-checkbox v-model="top" label="Top" hide-details></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox v-model="right" label="Right" hide-details></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox v-model="bottom" label="Bottom" hide-details></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox v-model="left" label="Left" hide-details></v-checkbox>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
            <v-subheader>Speed dial direction</v-subheader>
            <v-radio-group v-model="direction" hide-details>
              <v-radio value="top" label="Top"></v-radio>
              <v-radio value="right" label="Right"></v-radio>
              <v-radio value="bottom" label="Bottom"></v-radio>
              <v-radio value="left" label="Left"></v-radio>
            </v-radio-group>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
            <v-subheader>Transition</v-subheader>
            <v-radio-group v-model="transition" hide-details>
              <v-radio value="slide-y-transition" label="Slide y"></v-radio>
              <v-radio value="slide-y-reverse-transition" label="Slide y reverse"></v-radio>
              <v-radio value="slide-x-transition" label="Slide x"></v-radio>
              <v-radio value="slide-x-reverse-transition" label="Slide x reverse"></v-radio>
              <v-radio value="scale-transition" label="Scale"></v-radio>
            </v-radio-group>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
      <v-speed-dial
        v-model="fab"
        :top="top"
        :bottom="bottom"
        :right="right"
        :left="left"
        :direction="direction"
        :open-on-hover="hover"
        :transition="transition"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-btn
            v-model="fab"
            color="blue darken-2"
            dark
            fab
          >
            <v-icon v-if="fab">close</v-icon>
            <v-icon v-else>account_circle</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-btn fab dark small color="indigo" @click="connectDialog = true">
          <v-icon>mdi-shuffle-variant</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-speed-dial>
      <v-dialog
        v-model="connectDialog"
        persistent
        no-click-animation
        width="500"
      >
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Test</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
              color="blue darken-1"
              text
              @click="connectDialog = false"
              >Abbrechen</v-btn
            >
            <v-btn
              color="blue darken-1"
              text
              @click="connectDialog = false"
            >
              Verbinden
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>

<template>
  <div>


  <v-container align="center" fluid style="padding: 58px 0 0 0">
      <v-col>
        <v-card height="100%">

          <v-data-table
              class="mainTable"
              :headers="headers"
              :items="items"
              height="800px"
              items-per-page="20"
              :footer-props="{
        showFirstLastPage: true,
        firstIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-left',
        lastIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-right',
        prevIcon: 'mdi-minus',
        nextIcon: 'mdi-plus'
      }"
          >
            <template v-slot:top>
                  <v-row>
                  <v-col sm="1" md="1" lg="1" xl="1">
                <v-btn slot="activator" icon @click="dialog = true" id="dialog">
                  <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
                  <v-dialog
                      width="600px"
                      v-model="dialog"
                      hide-overlay
                  >
                    <SearchForDovid/>
                  </v-dialog>
                </v-btn>
                  </v-col>
                  </v-row>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>


  </v-container>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import SearchForDovid from "./SearchForDovid";
export default {
  name: "Dovid()",
data() {
    return{
      dialog: false,
      headers: [
        {name: 'schema', value: 'schema', text: 'schema', width: '8%'},
        {name: 'id', value: 'id', text: 'id', width: '8%'},
        {name: 'city_id', value: 'city_id', text: 'city_id', width: '8%'},
        {name: 'city_district_id', value: 'city_district_id', text: 'city_district_id', width: '8%'},
        {name: 'name', value: 'name', text: 'name', width: '30%'},
        {name: 'name_aliases', value: 'name_aliases', text: 'name_aliases', width: '30%'},
        {name: 'type', value: 'type', text: 'type', width: '16%'},
      ],
      items: [

        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '2',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
        {
          schema: 'rivne',
          id: '1',
          city_id : '1',
          city_district_id: '1',
          name: 'Бандери',
          name_aliases: 'Бандер',
          type: 'вул'
        },
      ]

    }
},
  components: {
    SearchForDovid
    // SearchForDovid
  },
}

</script>
```

Comment: Why not use v-menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide overlay of v-dialog
`<v-dialog v-model="dialog" hide-overlay>` and then specify position by css

```
.v-dialog__content{
    top: 20px !important;
}
```